# temporary lookup failure error using postfix with ldap

Tags: lookup, temporary

I have setup docker-mailserver image on ubuntu VM of aws cloud. I have configured a separate image of openldap on the same VM. I also have added the enteries of
cn=abc,ou=people,dc=x,dc=y,dc=z,dc=com
When I try to do ldapsearch to fetch the above entry I am able to do that. But, when I send mail from another ubuntu VM using the script and using this mail server it gives an error of "Temporary lookup failure, Can't contact LDAP server"
I have set up a user-defined bridge between the two containers and I am able to telnet each of them from the /bin/bash of other.

This is my docker-compose.yml file of my mail-server container,

```
version: '2' 
 services:   
   mail:
    restart: always
    image: abc/docker-mailserver:latest    
    hostname: x
    domainname: y.z.com
    container_name: mail
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "143:143"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
      - "389:389"
      - "636:636"
    volumes:
      - maildata:/var/mail
      - mailstate:/var/mail-state
      - ./spamassassin:/tmp/spamassassin/
      - ./postfix:/tmp/postfix/
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
    environment:
      - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=1
      - ENABLE_CLAMAV=1
      - ENABLE_MANAGESIEVE=1
      - SA_TAG=2.0
      - SA_TAG2=6.31
      - SA_KILL=6.31
      - SSL_TYPE=letsencrypt
      - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
      - ENABLE_POSTGREY=1
      - ONE_DIR=1
      - DMS_DEBUG=0
          {
      - ENABLE_LDAP=1
      - LDAP_SERVER_HOST= ldap-server-ip # your ldap container/IP/ServerName
      - LDAP_SEARCH_BASE=cn=abc,ou=people,dc=x,dc=y,dc=z,dc=com
      - LDAP_BIND_DN=cn=admin,dc=x,dc=y,dc=z,dc=com
      - LDAP_BIND_PW=***
      - LDAP_QUERY_FILTER_USER="(&(mail=%s)(mailEnabled=TRUE))"
      - LDAP_QUERY_FILTER_GROUP="(&(mailGroupMember=%s)(mailEnabled=TRUE))"
      - LDAP_QUERY_FILTER_ALIAS="(&(mailAlias=%s)(mailEnabled=TRUE))"
      }

      - DOVECOT_PASS_FILTER="(&(objectClass=*)(uniqueIdentifier=%n))"  #    - DOVECOT_USER_FILTER="(&(objectClass=PostfixBookMailAccount)(uniqueIdentifier=%n))"
          {
      - ENABLE_SASLAUTHD=1
      - SASLAUTHD_MECHANISMS=ldap
      - SASLAUTHD_LDAP_SERVER= ldap-server-ip
      - SASLAUTHD_LDAP_BIND_DN=cn=admin,dc=x,dc=y,dc=z,dc=com
      - SASLAUTHD_LDAP_PASSWORD=***
      - SASLAUTHD_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE=cn=abc,ou=people,dc=x,dc=y,dc=z,dc=com
      - POSTMASTER_ADDRESS=postmaster@x.y.z.com
      - MAIL_USER=user@x.y.z.com
      - MAIL_PASS=******
      - LDAP_QUERY_FILTER_DOMAIN="(&(|(mail=*@%s)(mailalias=*@%s)(mailGroupMember=*@%s))(mailEnabled=TRUE))"      }

      # >>> Kopano Integration
      - ENABLE_POSTFIX_VIRTUAL_TRANSPORT=1
      - POSTFIX_DAGENT=lmtp:kopano:2003
      # <<< Kopano Integration
      - PERMIT_DOCKER=host
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_PTRACE volumes:   maildata:
    driver: local   mailstate:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the LDAP also running in Docker? If yes then it is probably beneficial to put both services into the same compose file and work with the container name instead of the IP.